# Saving messages from mailx command line

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, mailx

Is there a way to save messages to a file using mailx, using only the command line? I know that I can copy messages to a file by first entering mailx:

```
mailx -A my_account
```

Then typing

```
& c 1-10 first_ten_messages.txt
```

Which would save the first 10 messages to a file.

What i'd like to do is something similar but without having the interactive part. So something like:

```
mailx -A my_account --options "c 1-10 first_ten_messages.txt"
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you insist on a `mailx` solution?  Because a script would probably make more sense.  `formail -10s <"$MAIL" >first_ten_messages.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it.

```
echo 'c 1-10 first_ten_messages.txt' | mailx -A my_account
```

If you want to select messages from specific a specific sender, you can run a similar command:

```
echo 'c from "Baji Boo" from_baji_boo.txt' | mailx -A my_account.
```

It is important to note that `from` works with the **enveloped** name, not straight email address.

In general, running `mailx` and typing `h` will give you good information as well as reading `man mailx`.

You can search messages in different ways and save to a file using the `echo` method.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how I can make it save messages from a certain sender something like `c (from name@email.com) from_sender.txt` instead of specifying the message number?

Comment: I added a solution to the answer above.